# UITableViewCell animation is hit or miss. Sometimes table data/cells just pop in without the animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I'm using a custom animation for how the table cells appear. They sort of fade in and slide up a little. I'm populating the table with data from an API call.

What I'm noticing is that it doesn't always happen. Sometimes it works as expected, other times the cells/data just appear abruptly, no animation/movement. They just sort of pop in at what would would be the end of the animation. I don't really see any consistent pattern in when it works and when it doesn't. Seems pretty random.

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Here's the code for the animation and where it is in the tableview function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    var cell: RecentActivityCell = recentActivityView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! RecentActivityCell
    
    var lastInitialDisplayableCell = false

        //change flag as soon as last displayable cell is being loaded (which will mean table has initially loaded)
    if userActivityArray.count > 0 && !finishedLoadingInitialTableCells {
            if let indexPathsForVisibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows,
                let lastIndexPath = indexPathsForVisibleRows.last, lastIndexPath.row == indexPath.row {
                lastInitialDisplayableCell = true
            }
        }

        if !finishedLoadingInitialTableCells {

            if lastInitialDisplayableCell {
                finishedLoadingInitialTableCells = true
            }

            //animates the cell as it is being displayed for the first time
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 40/2)
            cell.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.05*Double(indexPath.row), options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
                cell.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    
    if userActivityArray[indexPath.row].status == "Success" {
        cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "passImage")
    } else {
        cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "failImage")
    }
    
    cell.activity = userActivityArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @matt Where would you advise putting the animation code? I've tried putting the code in willDisplay as well, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your animation in "yourTableViewCell" by overriding:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        \\ Animation code over here
    }
```

**dont use in "CellForRowAt"**